How to allow/block multiple ip in GCP cloud armor?
I have a use case that requires creating policies to allow or block traffic based on a set of public IP addresses. From the GCP Cloud Armor console, I read that a single Cloud Armor policy only allows up to 10 IP CIDRs. The number of IP addresses ranges from 100 to 1000, making it impractical or inefficient to create policies manually to handle this. Does GCP have any provision similar to the IP set functionality in AWS WAF? If not, how can I implement this?
I have tested creating Basic mode rule with more than 10 IP address, but failed. I need to create rules for blacklisting IPs and whitelisting IPs.

According to this link, this is not a quota to increase it.
Google Cloud Armor has the following limits:



Item
Limits




Number of IP addresses or IP address ranges per rule
10


Number of subexpressions for each rule with a custom expression
5


Number of characters for each subexpression in a custom expression
1024


Number of characters in a custom expression
2048


Number of regular expression matches for each custom expression
5


Number of requests per second per project across all backends with a Google Cloud Armor security policy, This limit is not enforced. Google reserves the right to limit the volume of traffic that can be processed by all security policies on a per-project basis. Direct any requests for QPS increases to your account team.
20,000


Number of network edge security services per region per project
1



So you must create a rule per 10 IPs.

There is a new feature called Address Groups that allows you to have up to 150k IPv4 and 50K IPv6 addresses as a named list. The named list is maintained out of band and you call in the named list in your Cloud Armor policy as a single line entry. As you update the list of IPs in your Address Group, you don't need to change the Cloud Armor policy itself- it will automagiclly use the new list of IPs.
You would draft a rule like this:

evaluateAddressGroup('apple-private-relay-ip-list')

The bad news, Address Groups is only available as a backend policy in the Enterprise service level of Cloud Armor (PAYGO or annual subscription plans).
Depending on how your IPs are listed, you may be able to draft a RegEx value to encapsulate the CIDR range(s).
